# What is method "is" used for? What java library does it require?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Here is an example of `is` method:

```
assertThat(dynamicType.newInstance().toString(), is("Hello World!"));
```

Comment: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.0.0.0/org/hamcrest/core/Is.html#is-T-

Answer (score -1):

It is imported by

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
```